# javascript button click using curl

Tags: php, javascript, curl

I have parsed a page using curl and it contains some check box and a 'select all' and a 'submit' button . Clicking the button selects every check box.'select all' button triggers a javascript function which actually select all check box.

Now i need to click 'select all' and 'submit' button.How can I do this ??

Here is the button code:

```
input type="button" onclick="SelectAll(137)" value="Select All"
```

Here is the js function:

```
function SelectAll(n)
{
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    document.getElementById("ch"+i).checked=true;
}
```

Comment: Was I the only one to notice the `curl` reference in the question? Nobody else wonder if the select all + submit need to be done using `curl`?

Comment: "I have parsed a page using curl" What do you mean parsed, is it [the content] actually loaded in a browser?

Comment: yes...all chekboxes and buttons are loaded in a browser

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't. If you must use cURL, you'd have to manually craft the POST request yourself. This would involve finding the names of all the checkboxes and sending a bunch of `checkbox1=on&checkbox2=on&...` in the POST body. See http://davidwalsh.name/execute-http-post-php-curl for a general example of a POST request through cURL with PHP.

Another option would be to use something like [Selenium Web Driver](https://github.com/facebook/php-webdriver), which pretty much allows you to script a web browser like Firefox that can run JavaScript, click things, etc.

Answer (score -1):

Pass a parameter in with your Curl request that gets parsed by jQuery on its $(document).ready().  There's some plugins that help with parsing parameters.

Something like

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var buttonPress = $.param("buttonPress");
    if (buttonPress == true)
        $("#myButton").click();
});
```