# jQuery File Uploads with cURL

Tags: jquery, curl, file-upload, jquery-file-upload, blueimp

This is a pretty unorthodox use case, but I was wondering if it's possible.

I have a file upload page that uses blueimp's jQuery File Upload (angular JS), and it's great. Recently, someone asked if he could send files to the upload site directly from cli, if he's ssh'd into a machine. I realize there are a thousand other ways to get his files, but it would be neat if they could pass through the upload site.

The only lead I can really think of is to use cURL, but I'm not too familiar with it.

Here's what I've been trying so far:

`curl --data "Files[]=/tmp/mytestfile.txt" https://myuploadsite.com`

But that just prints the page contents.

If that method could work, I also don't know how to trigger blueimp's submit button. He's not using a form action to trigger the file upload. Could anyone familiar with jQuery File Upload point me in the right direction?

---

**Solved:** I ended up figuring this out. I couldn't find an easy way to programmatically interface with BlueImp's form, so I ended up just making another separate php file with a hidden form on it that just had my basic fields. Web users can use the BlueImp form, and cli users can use the basic one, since they both go to the same uploads directory.

To upload to the basic form, I have been using "curl -F" instead of "curl --data".

`curl -F "file=@<path to file>" -F "folder=<description>`

The php file handles the description part, and any other fields I want to use.

Comment: Does this answer, http://superuser.com/questions/149329/what-is-the-curl-command-line-syntax-to-do-a-post-request, help at all? Or possible, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10937646/javascript-button-click-using-curl.

Comment: Whoops. I figured this out the next day and forgot to update my post. I did end up doing something along those lines, thanks!

I'm going to update my post and close it.